# Is it alright to post a beta game in here?

Tags: discussion

We are some students from Aalborg University - CPH in Denmark, and we have created a tower defence game. So far we have been doing some alpha testing, but now it's time for some beta testing. Our question is, are  we allowed to post our game in here for testing?

Comment: No it is not. This site is for programming questions.

Comment: Ask these kind of questions at meta.stakcexchange.com

Comment: @ArslanAli: No. This question is on the correct site here.

Comment: @juergend, it wasn't on a meta at all when he commented

Comment: Why am I getting downvoted? I am just asking a question..

Comment: @Shadiay Downvotes on meta means "I disagree"

Comment: I would like to thank everyone for your help, we will try some other places

Comment: Sadly no however I'd be more than happy to test out your game! Shoot me an email: francisj12@icloud.com with the game file.

Answer (score 10):

Stack Overflow is about programming questions, beta testing your game is completely off-topic there.

If you're looking for testers for your game you could try to ask [on the Bridge, the chat room of the SE gaming community](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge). There might be an issue depending on how exactly you distribute your game, many user might not want to run executables from an unkown source.